# How to make a timer that returns the amount of time passed after mouse is released

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent

For example you press your RMB and keep it for 3 seconds then release. So the function will return 3.

```
running = True
timer = 0

while running:
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed(3)[2]:
      timer += 33.3
elif timer:
      print("%.2f" % (timer / 1000))
      timer = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type = pygame.QUIT:
           running = False

pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

Is it a good practice?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html) it states that you have `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`. so check the time with `time.time()`  when pressed down and check the difference when released(pressed up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
import pygame
import time

#create window
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

#take start time, end time and bool is mouse is pressed
def get_time(start, end, pressed):

    #calculate time
    timer = end - start

    #return timer if it is pressed
    if pressed:
        return timer


#get start time
start = time.time()

while True:
    pygame.event.get()

    #get if RMB is pressed
    pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]

    #calculate current time
    now = time.time()

    #call the function and store the return value in a variable
    timepressed = get_time(start, now, pressed)

    #print the value
    print(timepressed)
```

EDIT:: I have left the code above as well for reference but below is the code that only returns the value when mouse is released. It used `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`. I also made it a class just to avoid having to declare everything global.

```
import pygame
import time

#create window
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        #start time
        self.start = time.time()

        #timer is the amount of time passed after mouse is pressed
        self.timer = 0

        #mouse button up
        self.up = False

        #mouse button down
        self.down = False

        #if rmb is held down
        self.rmb = False

        #now 
        self.now = 0


    #update now
    def update(self):
        self.now = time.time()


    def timeRMB(self):
        #if rmb is pressed and pygame mouse button down is true
        if self.rmb:
            if self.down:
                #actual timer
                self.timer = self.now - self.start

        else:
            #if mouse button up is true
            if self.up:
                #reset the timer 
                self.start = self.now
                return self.timer
            
        

#get start time
timer = Timer()

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    #get if RMB is pressed
    timer.rmb = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]


    #get mouse events
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            timer.down = True
        if not event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
             timer.down = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            timer.up = True
        if not event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            timer.up = False

    timer.update()

    #call the function and store the return value in a variable
    timepressed = timer.timeRMB()

    print(timepressed)
```

Comment: Better use " if event.button == 3 "